# Python code to divide a list of aspects by percent of importance

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, percentage

I need to order a number of aspects by their importance, the way to evaluate that importance is numerical, therefore I want to divide these aspects into percentages from highest to lowest.

I'm going to explain myself better. This are the aspects ordered by importance, as you can see I want to automatically represent every one of the aspects by a decrescent percentage value which total sum is of course 100%:

```
Python ----------> 40 %

RobotFramework --> 30 %

C ---------------> 20 %

JavaScrip -------> 10 %
```

And this is the code itself:

```
Quantity_Of_Aspects = 5
Total_Percentage = 100
List_Of_Percentages = []
i = Quantity_Of_Aspects


while Quantity_Of_Aspects > 1:
    Biggest_Percentage = Total_Percentage / (i - 1)
    i = i + 1
    Quantity_Of_Aspects = Quantity_Of_Aspects - 1
    Total_Percentage = Total_Percentage - Biggest_Percentage
    List_Of_Percentages.append(Biggest_Percentage)

print(List_Of_Percentages)
```

By now it gives me this:
[25.0, 15.0, 10.0, 7.142857142857143]

As you can note, it does not even sum 100% and do not show me the 5 aspects I want, can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a function that gives you a list of percentages that sum up to 100%, with a parameter for the length of the list (ie the number of components):

```
def percents(n, total_percent=100):
    assert isinstance(n, int) and n > 0
    return [x / sum(range(n+1)) * total_percent for x in range(1, n+1)]
```

Result:

```
percents(4)
# > [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0]

percents(8)
# > [2.7777777777777777,
#    5.555555555555555,
#    8.333333333333332,
#    11.11111111111111,
#    13.88888888888889,
#    16.666666666666664,
#    19.444444444444443,
#    22.22222222222222]

sum(percents(45))
# > 100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Reframing your problem, you want the second last to be the double of the last, the third last to be the triple, etc. We can create such an arithmetic series with `numpy` and then normalize it:

```py
import numpy as np

Quantity_Of_Aspects = 5
Total_Percentage = 100

List_Of_Percentages = np.arange(Quantity_Of_Aspects, 0, -1) 
#> [5,4,3,2,1]    
List_Of_Percentages = List_Of_Percentages/np.sum(List_Of_Percentages) * Total_Percentage 
#> [5,4,3,2,1] / (5+4+3+2+1) * 100
```

For `Quantity_Of_Aspects=5` this yields: `array([33.33, 26.67, 20. , 13.3,  6.67])`, which adds up to 100. If you need it in `list` format, you can do `list(List_Of_Percentages)`.